# Retrieving project coverage with python-gitlab

Tags: gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

I use the [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io) module to retrieve the project statistics for a number of projects in Gitlab via its API. One of the values I want to get is the CI status and the code coverage. While the status is easy:

```py
from gitlab import Gitlab
gl = Gitlab('http://gitlab.example.com')
project = gl.projects.get('olebole/myproject')
branch = project.branches.get(project.default_branch)
commit = project.commits.get((branch.commit['id'])
print(commit.last_pipeline['status'])
```

I didn't find a way to retrieve the coverage; also adding `with_stats=True` to the commit retrieval didn't make it.

How can one get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the `pipeline` object:

```py
pipeline = project.pipelines.get(commit.last_pipeline['id'])
print(pipeline.status, pipeline.coverage)
```